# Ladder bug in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I've made a script that lets a player to climb on ladders. I'm using slightly modified FPS prefab from "FREE Footstep System" Unity asset. The bug is that when you climb up on the ladder everything works properly but when you go down on the ladder you can go under the floor. Plus, when you leave the trigger, player moves forward a bit to avoid sticking. So, anti-sticking function is performed, but everything else doesn't. How to fix it?

UPD: Whoops, forgot the code!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClimbOnLadder : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool isClimbing = false;
    private Transform playerTransform;
    private Vector3 newPlayerPosition;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider colliderEntered)
    {
        if (colliderEntered.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            isClimbing = true;
            colliderEntered.gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
            colliderEntered.gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = true;
            colliderEntered.gameObject.GetComponent<Footsteps.FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
            colliderEntered.gameObject.GetComponent<Footsteps.CharacterFootsteps>().enabled = false;
            playerTransform = colliderEntered.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider colliderLeft)
    {
        if (colliderLeft.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            isClimbing = false;
            newPlayerPosition.Set(gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().localPosition.x + 0.125F, playerTransform.localPosition.y + 0.25F, playerTransform.localPosition.z);
            playerTransform.position = newPlayerPosition;
            colliderLeft.gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
            colliderLeft.gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;
            colliderLeft.gameObject.GetComponent<Footsteps.FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
            colliderLeft.gameObject.GetComponent<Footsteps.CharacterFootsteps>().enabled = true;
            playerTransform = null;
            newPlayerPosition.Set(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isClimbing)
        {
            newPlayerPosition.Set(playerTransform.localPosition.x, playerTransform.localPosition.y + (Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*0.0675F), playerTransform.localPosition.z);
            playerTransform.localPosition = newPlayerPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your ladder reach in the floor? You normally stop before connecting to the floor.

Comment: You'll need to add the code to your question, rather than a picture of it.

Comment: Woah. Somehow I partually managed to fix this bug by fixing the collider position. Now the whole OnTriggerExit function works. Yay!

Comment: Hi @ArtyomIsFlash - would you mind clicking "delete" to avoid clutter on the site?  Don't hesitate to come back with new questions, I'm sure you'll have many good ones.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'll better answer my own question. Just close the question.

Comment: Hi @ArtyomIsFlash.  It would have been better if you had deleted it, as I said.  That's why I said it.  Now that you have answered it, you should "Tick" your own answer.  You might have to wait until tomorrow.  Please don't forget.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woah. Somehow I partually managed to fix this bug by fixing the collider position. Now the whole OnTriggerExit function works. Yay!

UPD: Fully fixed the problem. Removed anti-sticking code because it's not needed anymore and moved the ladder higher.